# How to avoid character controller collider for slide over floor.?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a character controller to move my player on a surface. All the things work fine, but I can't make a perfect slide with the character controller on the surface.

When I try to slide, my player animation plays in the center of capsule collider, which is attached to the  player. That's why my player can not touch floor, which means my animation play in mid air. After some time I found that my problem occurs due to using the character controller. I am using `Character.Move()` to move my player.

**Can anyone help me? How can I avoid the collider on the character controller, or change something to make my player slide animation perfectly align with the floor.?**

I am using `controller.transform.Rotate(0,0,60)` to rotate my player on floor.

**This is my script:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Scripts;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ControllerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
public float gravity = 20f;
private CharacterController controller;
public float JumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float Speed = 0.1f;
public int swipeStep = 3;
int swipeD,pos;
bool rx ;
int i=0;
public Transform CharacterGO;
bool isInSwipeArea;
private Animator anim;
IInputDetector inputDetector = null;

// Use this for initialization

void Start()
{
    moveDirection = transform.forward;
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= Speed;
    UIManager.Instance.ResetScore();
    UIManager.Instance.SetStatus(Constants.StatusTapToStart);
    GameManager.Instance.GameState = GameState.Start;

    anim = CharacterGO.GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ();
    inputDetector = GetComponent<IInputDetector>();
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    switch (GameManager.Instance.GameState)
    {
    case GameState.Start:
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            //anim.SetBool(Constants.animaationStarted, true);
            var instance = GameManager.Instance;
            instance.GameState = GameState.Playing;
            UIManager.Instance.SetStatus(string.Empty);
        }
        break;
    case GameState.Playing:
        UIManager.Instance.IncreaseScore (0.001f);
        CheckHeight ();
        DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight ();


        //apply gravity
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        //move the player
        controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
        break;

    case GameState.Dead:
        ////anima.SetBool(Constants.//animaationStarted, false);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {         SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
private void CheckHeight()
{
    if (transform.position.y < -10)
    {
        GameManager.Instance.Die();
    }
}

private void DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight()
{
    var inputDirection = inputDetector.DetectInputDirection();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        moveDirection.y = JumpSpeed;
        anim.SetBool ("RunToJump", true);
    } else {
        anim.SetBool ("RunToJump", false);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && controller.isGrounded){
        controller.transform.Translate (-0.1f,0,0);         
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && controller.isGrounded){
        controller.transform.Translate (0.1f,0,0);          
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S) && controller.isGrounded) {                                    
        anim.SetBool ("RunToSlip", true);
        controller.transform.Rotate (-40, 0, 0);
        Invoke ("StopSlidding", 0.2f);
    } 
        }
 void StopSlidding(){       
    anim.SetBool ("RunToSlip", false);
    controller.transform.Rotate (40,0,0);

  }

 }
```

Comment: Do you have both animator and character controller in one object or you maintained a parent child hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I have both in single object. @SP.

Comment: It should be `anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ();` if the character object is as child. This has noting to do with parent rotation. You should usually rotate parent object not trying with `ChracterController`.

Comment: still sucking same problem.. @SP.

Comment: Not sure why trying to rotate `CharacterController` component. You rotate the parent transform usually. There is [movement control](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) for character controller.

Comment: I have sliding animation like temple run character. so my player must slide on floor because I have sated obstacle for floor sliding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44185/discussion-between-sp-and-hardwork).

Answer (score 1):

Change your sliding animation with translated down position and use root motion of this animation in Unity.

Or use a parent child setup for controlling a character or figure.

In parent keep the Scripts, CharacterController component.

In child keep the character body with animator component.

In the script use `GetComponentInChildren<Animator>()` instead of `GetComponent<Animator>()`.

When sliding, translate down the child as you need towards ground. Go back to normal position when not sliding. You can resize height of the `CharacterController` if you need.

You can do it in same object but above way keeps them separate and interfering with each other with better control.

Comment: I tried your script but it cant rotate my collider for every time, It just Rotate it only first time. This is my code  `if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S) && controller.isGrounded) {         
   anim.SetBool ("RunToSlip", true);
   controller.transform.Rotate (-40, 0, 0);
   Invoke ("StopSlidding", 0.2f);
  }  ` and this ` void StopSlidding(){  
  anim.SetBool ("RunToSlip", false);
  controller.transform.Rotate (40,0,0);

 }
`

Comment: I can't change character controller height because I  must have to keep collider for full body mesh.

Comment: Add you code at question details.

Comment: I  add my code see it.

Comment: I think `controller.transform.Rotate()` work before  invoke() method start. that's why my player character collider not rotate as I want.

And Also Controller rotation not stay with `invoke()` method to start. controller rotate to zero position before `invoke()` method start.

Comment: My solution is focused on leveling your character and animation to floor when sliding instead of staying in the mid air. Think you are getting side tracked.

Comment: I seem to remember a similar-ish question semi-recently (I think you might have posted on it) where the asker wanted to ignore a collider and did so through setting the colliders to ignore (again, IIRC this was through "collider layers", Im not overly sure). Does this method ring a bell? would it be a suitable alternative, in this situation?

Comment: Yes But this is problem with character collider. and I can not keep my character collider to 40 degree rotate on z-axis till invoke(0 method start. so my player play sliding animation on center point of collider. which is at half length of the character controller. I try your answer but it can not solve my problem it. I still stand with this problem. 
Anyway thanks for help me. If you got solution then please post hear.

Answer (score -1):

@hardwork, I think, and if I read your question right, you could change the location of the animating part, not the controller, whiile it's sliding to have not so mid air. Then, change it back to it's normal location later on. In javaScript, you'd use "transform.position", but I'm not sure if that is it in C#. You can type in that under the Js search, then swap it over to C#.

Comment: I say above it's problem with collider not with animation parts or character position. just try to look other related question on this topic. 

And transform.position is not any kind of solution for collider.